# ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 is throwing exception with SelectByVisibleText method: Script returns unexpected result

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have updated the selenium chromedriver to 76.0.3809.68 and the existing tests started to fail with new `Select(webElement).selectByVisibleText(value)` is failing with the following exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: script returns unexpected result
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.87)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'VARGHESEV10', ip: '10.13.36.28', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: com.prahs.framework.PRAWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 76.0.3809.87, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce..., userDataDir: C:\Users\swqatest\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:15612}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: cfd7ddc498272f40f9b62c43f67...}
Session ID: cfd7ddc498272f40f9b62c43f6742060
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//option[normalize-space(.) = "Test_Auto_Pv_243399_RAJ"]}


protected void selectOption(String field, WebElement selectElement, String value) {
    log.info(ReportUtils.formatAction("Select ", field, value));
    Select select = new Select(selectElement);
    select.selectByVisibleText(value);
}
```

Comment: show html structure of element

Comment: <select name="j_id0:formid:j_id33:j_id45:j_id76" size="1" onchange="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:formid',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:formid:j_id33:j_id45:j_id78','containerId':'j_id0:formid:j_id33:actionRegion1','parameters':{'j_id0:formid:j_id33:j_id45:j_id78':'j_id0:formid:j_id33:j_id45:j_id78'} ,'status':'j_id0:formid:sts'} )"><option value="">-Select-</option><option value="aKc0R00000000YwSAI">Test_Auto_Pv_243399_DTv</option></select>

Comment: Check if this version of chromedriver is compatible with your current chrome version. If not, upgrade chrome to compatible version.

Comment: I have upgraded both Chrome and Chrome driver to 76 version

Comment: This issue occurred after upgrading these versions, if there is no solution, then i will go and degrade to older version

Comment: Good news is V75 driver does seem to work with Chrome V76.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but working fine after downgrading Driver version: Chrome is 76 (76.0.3809.100) and Driver is 75 (75.0.3770.140)

Comment: This worked for me, nice to know you can still use chromedrive 75

Answer (score 1):

Not really a fix but this is due to the fix made for issue 3084: Find Elements not working properly in ChromeDriver 76 when prototype.js 1.6.1 is used [Pri-2]`, select tags are not working. Just the presence of`prototype.js` is enough this to be failed. You can try the following to recreate

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select id="sample">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: script returns unexpected result
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
```

If you have the control of the application you can upgrade the version of `prototype.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue but working as expected,  after updating Chrome to Version 76.0.3809.87 and driver to latest

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue with ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 and Chrome 76.0.3809.100.
It works with ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 and Chrome 76.0.3809.100.

Answer (score 0):

Not just `selectByVisibleText` even `selectByValue` was also throwing the same Exception

> "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: script returns
>   unexpected result".

I faced this issue with chrome v76. **I upgraded the chrome version to 77** and tested with ChromeDriver 76 and 77 which works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fix for this issue was released in chrome 76.0.3809.126, please check.