# I get script returns unexpected result error in selenium, after update v76

Tags: c#, selenium

I get script returns unexpected result error in selenium, after update v76

```
browser.FindElements(By.LinkText("TEST"));
```

unknown error: script returns unexpected result (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.87)

Comment: Does you Selenium Chrome driver supports version of Chrome you have installed on your PC?

Comment: might be a bug in latest chromedriver, there was this post reporting this, too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315463/chromedriver-76-0-3809-68-is-throwing-exception-with-selectbyvisibletext-method

Comment: Lemm ;Google Chrome güncel durumda
76.0.3809.87 (Resmi Derleme) (64 bit) Sürümü

Comment: this code also doesn't work 

//var teminatlist = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'form:panel')]"));

Comment: SelectElement also does not work , my apps are ruined

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/005a942a5ce0a63a5917c3eb7386c02a2de8700b. Set useSpecCompliantProtocol  to false and may be related to w3c default mode in New chrome driver

Comment: i will try tomorrow, thank you for the answer  Rahul L

Answer (score 1):

This work for me, i changed my code from:

```
select.selectByValue(value)
```

to:

```
public void selectOptionByValue(Select select, String value) {
    if (select == null || value == null) {
        return;
    }
    var options = select.getOptions();

    if (options == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (var option : options) {
        if (value.equals(option.getAttribute("value"))) {
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```