# I got error like script returns unexpected result while running selenium test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using latest chrome version(76.0.3809.100) and selenium latest version(3.141.59) with latest webdriver manager version(3.6.2) and issue is occuring showing script return unexpected result.

As per search related to this problem on stackoverflow i have checked all links and tried with upgrading each chrome and selenium but none works.

Here is the pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code that is accessing xpath

```
List<WebElement> allVINs = null;
try {
         allVINs =     driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@target='_blank']"));
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.info("Something wrong with storing element in the list and the issue is: " + e1);
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I expect to run it  successfully without errors but it shows exception like below

```
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: script returns unexpected result
(Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:'2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'PC name', ip: 'ipAddress', os.name: 'Windows 10',     os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome,     browserVersion: 76.0.3809.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce..., userDataDir: C:\Users\VIVEK~1.SIN\AppDat...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59659}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: dbb14cb4d3a103864093b7d121bd29f0
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[@target='_blank']}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:432)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElements(By.java:348)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
at com.Adesa.Utilities.WebDriverUtils.getVINlist(WebDriverUtils.java:896)
at com.Adesa.Utilities.Environment.WriteExcelData(Environment.java:76)
at com.Adesa.Actions.DDO.DDOActions.createExcelFileToUpload(DDOActions.java:41)
at com.Adesa.Local.TestCases.DDO.DDOFunctionalTestCases.AddVINsToDDOTest(DDOFunctionalTestCases.java:24)
at com.Adesa.Local.TestCases.Functional.Admin_FunctionalTestCases.AdminFunctionalTestCases(Admin_FunctionalTestCases.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Getting exception on the following line: allVINs =     driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@target='_blank']"));

Comment: Is it working in Firefox / gecko driver ? Or you are getting  same error

Comment: You're not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329519/i-get-script-returns-unexpected-result-error-in-selenium-after-update-v76  May be related to "w3c" option?: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5261

Comment: It is working fine in Firefox browser / gecko driver.

Comment: As suggested for chrome set  w3c=false  and check  options.setExperimentalOption("w3c", false);

Comment: After setting w3c=false, it is still not working.

Comment: temporary workaround is to downgrade the browser to 75. It is obviously a problem with chromedriver

Comment: Try downgrading your chromedriver to 75 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315463/chromedriver-76-0-3809-68-is-throwing-exception-with-selectbyvisibletext-method)